# Bash variable to camel case / pascal case

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

in bash getting something replaced by upper cases is super easy :

```
echo to_camel_case__variable | sed -r 's/(.)_+(.)/\1\U\2/g;s/^[a-z]/\U&/'
```

but what if I don't want to replace? what if I simply want to make the variable pascal case, yet keep the underscores?

Comment: Note that the command you gave above doesn't work everywhere bash does -- it depends on your `sed` (which is provided by your OS, not part of bash) having nonstandard extensions.

Comment: oh yeah good point sed isn't always installed.

Comment: well, sed *is* always installed (on POSIX-compliant platforms), but it isn't always GNU sed; the only features `sed` is guaranteed to offer are the ones documented at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html -- `\U` is not in that set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a pure-bash implementation with no dependencies on external tools (albeit requiring modern bash 4.x):

```
case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[123].*) echo "ERROR: Bash 4.x+ required" >&2; exit 1;; esac

to_pascal_with_underscores() {
  local s=${1^} re='(.*_+)([[:lower:]].*)'    # initially capitalize 1st char
  while [[ $s =~ $re ]]; do                   # match string $s against regex $re
    s=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]^}   # capitalize first character of 2nd group
  done
  printf '%s\n' "$s"                          # avoid unreliable behavior associated w/ echo
}

to_pascal_with_underscores this_is_a_test
to_pascal_with_underscores to_camel_case__variable
```

...properly emits `This_Is_A_Test` and `To_Camel_Case__Variable`, as can be seen at https://ideone.com/yen0T2

Comment: what's the syntax for storing into variable. the function itself works in my shell but storing into variable doesn't

Comment: `var=$(to_pascal_with_underscores this_is_a_test)` -- same way you'd store the output from the `echo | sed` pipeline.

Comment: ...that said, if you wanted to make it more efficient, you could take a destination variable name as a second argument and do `printf -v "$2" %s "$s"`, avoiding the performance overhead involved in command substitutions.

Comment: OH wait! if there is a preceding number before the underscore it fails

Comment: `i_wanted11_to_be_upper`

Comment: You can just make it `(.*_+)` for that first group if you don't care what's before the underscore.

Comment: `local s=${1^} re='(.*_+)'` instead of `local s=${1^} re='(.*_+)([[:lower:]].*)' `?

Comment: I already edited the answer -- click the "edited [amount-of-time] ago" link to see exactly what changed and when. It was `re='(.*[[:lower:]]_+)([[:lower:]].*)'` before; the only thing that needs to change is taking out the *first* `[[:lower:]]` (the second needs to stay).

Answer (score 5):

this works :

```
echo 'this_is_a_test' | sed 's/[^_]\+/\L\u&/g'
```

I'll test a bit but seems reliable.